# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ ... } cannot be found

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement navigation in an app with the following expected flow:

1. List of categories displayed from whom a user can select
2. List of recommendations associated with a given category from which a user can select is displayed
3. User clicks on a listed recommendation and the details of that recommendation shows up

The listing of categories and recommendations works, however, when clicking on a given recommendation the app crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/Recommendation/{recommendationId} } cannot be found in the navigation graph ComposeNavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x6bf0b589) route=Categories}
```

The code is the following:

```kotlin
sealed class MyCityScreen(val route: String) {
    object Categories: MyCityScreen("Categories")
    object Recommendations: MyCityScreen("Recommendations")
    object Recommendation: MyCityScreen("Recommendation/{recommendationId}")
}

@Composable
fun MyCityApp(
    windowSize: WindowWidthSizeClass,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val viewModel: MyCityViewModel = viewModel()
    val myCityUiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState().value

    val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

    val contentType: MyCityContentType = when (windowSize) {
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Compact -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_ONLY
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Medium -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_ONLY
        }
        WindowWidthSizeClass.Expanded -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_AND_DETAIL
        }
        else -> {
            MyCityContentType.LIST_ONLY
        }
    }

    if (contentType != MyCityContentType.LIST_AND_DETAIL) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = MyCityScreen.Categories.route
        ) {
            composable(route = MyCityScreen.Categories.route) {
                val categories = myCityUiState.categories

                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(
                            end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.list_and_detail_list_padding_end),
                            top = dimensionResource(R.dimen.list_and_detail_list_padding_top)
                        ),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
                        dimensionResource(R.dimen.recommendation_list_padding)
                    )
                ) {
                    items(categories, key = { category -> category.id }) { category ->
                        MyCityCategoryListItem(
                            category = category,
                            selected = myCityUiState.currentSelectedRecommendation.id == category.id,
                            onCardClick = {
                                viewModel.updateRecommendations(category)
                                navController.navigate(MyCityScreen.Recommendations.route)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            composable(route = MyCityScreen.Recommendations.route) {
                val recommendations = myCityUiState.currentRecommendations

                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(
                            end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.list_and_detail_list_padding_end),
                            top = dimensionResource(R.dimen.list_and_detail_list_padding_top)
                        ),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
                        dimensionResource(R.dimen.recommendation_list_padding)
                    )
                ) {
                    items(recommendations, key = {
                            recommendation -> recommendation.id
                    }) { recommendation ->
                        MyCityRecommendationListItem(
                            recommendation = recommendation,
                            selected =
                                myCityUiState.currentSelectedRecommendation.id == recommendation.id,
                            onCardClick = {
                                navController.navigate(
                                    MyCityScreen.Recommendation.route
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            composable(
                route = MyCityScreen.Recommendation.route,
                arguments = listOf(navArgument("recommendationId") {
                    type = NavType.IntType
                })
            ) { backStackEntry ->
                val recommendationId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("recommendationId")
                val recommendation =
                    myCityUiState.currentRecommendations[recommendationId!!]

                MyCityRecommendationDetailsCard(
                    recommendation = recommendation,
                    isFullScreen = false
                )
            }
        }
    } else {
        MyCityHomeScreen(
            contentType = contentType,
            myCityUiState = myCityUiState,
            onCategoryCardPressed = {
                viewModel.updateDetailsScreenStates(
                    category = myCityUiState.currentSelectedCategory,
                    recommendation = myCityUiState.currentSelectedRecommendation
                )
            },
            onDetailScreenBackPressed = {
                viewModel.resetHomeScreenStates()
            },
            onRecommendationCardPressed = {
                viewModel.updateDetailsScreenStates(
                    category = myCityUiState.currentSelectedCategory,
                    recommendation = myCityUiState.currentSelectedRecommendation
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

The route is defined and it is

```kotlin
object Recommendation: MyCityScreen("Recommendation/{recommendationId}")
```

so how come the navigation doesn't find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with

```kotlin
sealed class MyCityScreen(val route: String) {
    object Categories: MyCityScreen("Categories")
    object Recommendations: MyCityScreen("Recommendations")
    object Recommendation: MyCityScreen("Recommendation/{recommendationId}") {
        fun createRoute(recommendationId: Long) = "Recommendation/$recommendationId"
    }
}
```

and then calling `createRoute` in `Recommendations` route:

```kotlin
composable(route = MyCityScreen.Recommendations.route) {
                val recommendations = myCityUiState.currentRecommendations

                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(
                            end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.list_and_detail_list_padding_end),
                            top = dimensionResource(R.dimen.list_and_detail_list_padding_top)
                        ),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(
                        dimensionResource(R.dimen.recommendation_list_padding)
                    )
                ) {
                    items(recommendations, key = {
                            recommendation -> recommendation.id
                    }) { recommendation ->
                        MyCityRecommendationListItem(
                            recommendation = recommendation,
                            selected =
                                myCityUiState.currentSelectedRecommendation.id == recommendation.id,
                            onCardClick = {
                                navController.navigate(
                                    MyCityScreen.Recommendation.createRoute(recommendation.id)
                                )
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

however, now when I click on a recommendation that is not indexed as 0 I get an error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
```

Comment: Well, I solved `IndexOutOfBoundsException` by adding a property to the ui state consisting of a list of all recommendations; indexing into that list preserves order and the association <route, recommendation> seems to work - not something I really wanted (what I wanted was to index directly into the filtered list with proper indexing, however it seems this is not the case)